# Use a text file where each line is a parameter to pass to SQL*Plus

Tags: batch-file, cmd, parameters, sqlplus

I have a text file where each line is an id. It looks like this

```
008700200107044314929
0049RXPRISE9000000476
0049GMLCLT00000001021
0147RXPRISE0000094208
0111RXPRISE0000043962
0132GDLCLT00000001637
002120001126002858830
0148FI000000000153554
0021JT000000000536614
```

I want to use that file and pass each line as parameter to SQL*PLUS inside my batch file.

I want to do something like this :

```
sqlplus -l -s %cfg.pivot.user%/%cfg.pivot.pass%@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=%cfg.pivot.server%)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=%cfg.pivot.base%))) @%sql_histo% "%list_id_cli_temp%" >> %logfile%
```

%list_id_cli_temp% is my text file and %sql_histo% is my SQL command and it's like this

```
insert into xyz.clt_reinsert_histo select id_client, sysdate, code_societe , code_etabliss , date_session , date_heure , numero_ordre FROM xyz.ctransaction where id_client='&1';
```

But like this it is not working. Anyone got an idea to deal with this?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please be specific! Take a look at the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: But like what happens when it does not work?

Comment: The "insert" is not working. I can't pass all my variables from my text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to @aschipfl, i have used the for /F to loop inside my text file and extract my IDs.

```
for /F "tokens=1-10" %%a in (%list_id_cli_temp%) do (
    sqlplus -l -s %cfg.pivot.user%/%cfg.pivot.pass%@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=%cfg.pivot.server%)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=%cfg.pivot.base%))) @%sql_histo% "%%a" >> %logfile%
)
```

Like this, i take my first 10 lines and use %%a to get my ID from each line of the text file and pass it by parameter to my sql command

Comment: I do not think that "tokens=1-10" does what you think it does. `FOR /?`

Comment: @lit "tokens=1-10" takes from line 1 to line 10 in my text file

Comment: That is not what the documentation says in `FOR /?`.

Comment: @lit tokens=n  -> Specifies which numbered items to read from each line  (default = 1)    
    tokens=2,4,6 will cause the second, fourth and sixth items on each line to be processed.
    tokens=2-6 will cause the second, third, fourth, fifth and sixth items on each line to be processed.
    tokens=* will cause all items on each line to be processed.
    tokens=3* will process the third token and the 4th + all subsequent items, this can also be written as tokens=3,*

Comment: Using tokens= affects the number of `ITEMS` on each line`. It has nothing to do with the number of lines. You just got lucky that there is only one item on your lines, so it all went into %%a.

Comment: @lit Ok, thanks for the precision, i understood in a bad way the documentation.